# Print database_size from sp_spaceused

Tags: sql-server-2008, size, stored-procedures

Using SQL Server 2008, I have found that the database size can be obtained using

```
exec sp_spaceused
```

This procedure returns two tables:

```
database_name | database_size | unallocated space


reserved | data | index_size | unused
```

I would like to create a query where the only output of the SQL call is the value returned for database_size.  I do not want any extraneous output (no table headers, column names, etc).

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Another way to accomplish this without the creating database objects is to use the below query taken from the sp_spaceused stored procedure itself:

```
declare @dbsize bigint
declare @logsize bigint

select @dbsize = sum(convert(bigint,case when status & 64 = 0 then size else 0 end))
, @logsize = sum(convert(bigint,case when status & 64 <> 0 then size else 0 end))
from dbo.sysfiles

select ltrim(str((convert (dec (15,2),@dbsize) + convert (dec (15,2),@logsize)) 
* 8192 / 1048576,15,2) + ' MB') as Database_Size
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: You can't do what you want with `sp_spaceused`.

Longer answer: You may be able to do what you want with `sp_helpdb` and creative use of temporary tables.
[This bytes.com](http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/79567-how-do-i-select-column-sp_spaceused-into-local-variable) discussion includes one example which I've cleaned up and reproduced below:

```
create table dbo.DBs (
    dbname sysname,
    db_size varchar(20),
    owner sysname,
    dbid int,
    created datetime,
    status varchar(1000),
    compat int
)
go

insert into dbo.DBs
    exec sp_helpdb
go

select cast(replace(db_size, 'MB', '') as decimal(10,2))
       from dbo.DBs
       where dbname = 'SomeDatabase'
go
```